# Akka streams feedback loop in a graph is not working

Tags: akka-stream

I'm trying to build a graph that has a feedback loop for retries, but when running it the execution stops when encountering a first failure

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder ⇒
import GraphDSL.Implicits._

val in = Source(1 to 10).buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.fail)
val out = Sink.foreach(println)

// purely for logging purposes
val m2 = builder.add(Flow[Either[Int, Int]].map(i => {println("flow:" + i); i}))


val mapper = builder.add(Flow[Int].statefulMapConcat{ () =>
  var retries = 0
  i =>

  // deliberately fails to simulate failures
  // supposed to retry that element
  if (i == 3) {
    if (retries > 0){
      List(Right(i))
    } else {
      retries += 1
      List(Left(i))
    }
  } else {
    List(Right(i))
  }
})

val concat = builder.add(Concat[Int](2))

val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Either[Int, Int]](2))


in ~> concat.in(0)

concat.out ~> mapper ~> m2 ~> broadcast

broadcast.out(1).filter(_.isRight).map(_.right.get) ~> out
broadcast.out(0).filter(_.isLeft).map(_.left.get) ~> concat.in(1)


ClosedShape
})

graph.run()
```

`mapper` stateful flow - is supposed to do some arbitrary calculation and to track the retries, outputs Either instances, Right in case of success and Left in case of failures

Later I'm trying to redirect the failures back to the `concat` for retries and successes to the sink.

the output looks like this:

```
flow:Right(1)
1
flow:Right(2)
2
flow:Left(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't figured out why it doesn't work with `Broadcast`, but here is a working version with `Partition`:

```
val partition = builder.add(Partition[Either[Int, Int]](2, input => if (input.isRight) 0 else 1))
concat.out ~> mapper ~> m2 ~> partition.in
partition.out(0).map(_.right.get) ~> out
partition.out(1).map(_.left.get ) ~> concat.in(1)
```